# React-native: Is there way to listen to Color Scheme (Dark Mode) change?

Tags: react-native, ios-darkmode, android-dark-theme

The official guideline suggests checking if Dark Theme is enabled on each component render. This seems grossly wrong. Is there better way of keeping the dark mode up to date?

Answer (score -2):

https://github.com/codemotionapps/react-native-dark-mode
This is a library for tracking dark mode.
You can use context in order to pass a theme to all components and adjusting the theme to the mode